# Finding percentage of total for each item

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL database that tracks what students have gotten right and wrong on tests. It has columns Student, questionID, and trakStatus (which records Right/Wrong). What I would like to compile is a list by questionID of what percentage students have gotten correct for each one.

Currently, when I run my SQL line, it spits out a list of questionIDs but all with the same percentage calculation, the percentage for the last question. The output will look like this:

```
**QuestionID**   **Percentage**
1001              .2459
1002              .2459
1003              .2459
etc.
```

What I would like instead is a distinct percentage calc for each questionID. Here is the SQL I am using currently:

```
SELECT questionID, 
(SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM  storedQuestions 
WHERE trakStatus =  'Wrong') / 
(SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM  storedQuestions 
WHERE (
trakStatus =  'Wrong'
OR trakStatus =  'Right'
) ) AS Percentage
FROM storedQuestions
GROUP BY questionID
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. This seems like it should work. Any advice would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need subqueries, just conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT questionID, 
       SUM(trakStatus = 'Wrong') / SUM(trakStatus IN ('Wrong', 'Right')) as Percentage
FROM storedQuestions
GROUP BY questionID;
```

If `trackStatus` only takes on those two values, you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT questionID, 
       AVG(trakStatus = 'Wrong') as Percentage
FROM storedQuestions
GROUP BY questionID;
```

Comment: Wow, that's very simple. Thanks so much!